# Disable mipmapping in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, mipmaps

I would like to draw some of the same figures (with the same texture) on screen (OpenGL ES 2.0). These figures will be different in magnification and minification filters. And different states mipmapping.
The issue is: if I use mipmapping in draw any figure ( if I called glGenerateMipmap() function) I can't switch off mipmapping mode.
Is it possible to switch off mipmapping mode, if I call glGenerateMipmap() at least once?

Comment: Huh? I don't completely understand your question. Do you want to render the texture without mipmapping? Just use a non-mipmapped filter mode, doesn't have anything to do with `glGenerateMipmap`.

Comment: Sorry, I'm newbie in OpenGL ES 2.0, and maybe тot accurate in terms.
If I called glGenerateMipmap() function, can I switch off in further code?
For example:
`void Draw(Context *context) {
...
for (t = 0; t<context->numberShapes; t++) {
DrawShape(userData->shapePositionX[t], userData->shapePositionY[t],
userData->shapePositionZ[t], t); }
...
}
`
`void DrawShape(GLfloat offsetX, GLfloat offsetY,
  GLfloat offsetZ, int t) {
...
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tHandle);
if (shapeConfig[t].boolMipMap) {
 glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
...
glDrawArrays(...);
`

Comment: if in cycle I call ` glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` once, How can I switch off them in futher?

Comment: `glGenerateMipmap` only generates the smaller mipmap images (based on the top-level image). Those mipmaps are not used if you don't use a proper mipmapping filter mode (through `glTexParamteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, ...)`). Likewise shouldn't you call `glGenerateMipmap` each frame before rendering. Call it once after setting the base image of the texture. Like said it generates the mipmap images, those won't go away after they've been generated. What decides if mipmapping is actually used is the texture object's filter mode.

Comment: @ChristianRau Actually, your comment is a well-formed answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`glGenerateMipmap` only generates the smaller mipmap images (based on the top-level image). But those mipmaps are not used for filtering if you don't use a proper mipmapping filter mode (through `glTexParamteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_..._MIPMAP_...)`). So if you don't want your texture mipmap filtered, just disable it for this particular texture by setting either `GL_NEAREST` or `GL_LINEAR` as minification filter. Likewise does *not* calling `glGenerateMipmap` not mean that there is no mipmapping going on. A possible mipmapping filter mode (which is also the default for a newly created texture) will still be used, just that the mipmap images contain rubbish (or the texture is actually incomplete, resulting in implementation-defined behaviour, but usually a black texture).

Likewise you shouldn't call `glGenerateMipmap` each frame before rendering. Call it once after setting the base image of the texture. Like said it generates the mipmap images, those won't go away after they've been generated. What decides if mipmapping is actually used is the texture object's filter mode.